# How to use incremental mode in SonarQube?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1.2

I've trying to fiddle with SonarQube and now I'm learning about the **incremental** mode. In my understanding it should analyze only the changed files.

So my first test is just to run SonarQube twice on our project without any change. I run SonarQube (5.1.2) installed locally on windows 7 64-bit machine  with SSD drive and I7 CPU. We use java 1.7 and Maven 3.3.3. Our project is fairly big (~570 modules) of maven, most of them are java code. After I run a **prepare-agent** of **jacoco** along with my unit tests I understand that its time to run **sonar:sonar** and create a report.

So what I try is:

`mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=incremental -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco`

This runs for 20 minutes. Ok, now I run the same command again without doing any change and it still runs the same 20 minutes

So my question is - whether someone can explain me how to use the incremental mode correctly? I have a hard time understanding what I'm doing wrong, in my understanding the second run has to be much faster, otherwise I don't see any advantage over the preview mode here.

Thanks Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The incremental mode will analyze only changed files since latest "regular" analysis on server. So in your case you should first run a normal (now called "publish") analysis:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
```

Then your can use the incremental mode:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=incremental -Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
```

Comment: For anyone coming here after 2022: `-Dsonar.analysis.mode=incremental` has been deprecated. There is no replacement, on the forums they suggest using branch analysis of the commercial version.